# Passing secret keys securely to docker containers

Tags: key-management, docker

I want to pass a secret value needed by an app that runs in a Docker container. This particular container is short-lived -- it starts up, runs a command, and then terminates.

Method 1: Pass the value as an environment variable via the command line when starting the container (Docker supports this as a command line argument to starting a container). I feel like this is bad since the command will show up in process lists (with the key and all) on the host machine that started the docker container.

Method 2: Pass the value as an env variable via an env variable file. This solves the process list issue, but running `docker info` on the running container from the host shows a list of all the environment variables set for that container. This makes me believe Docker is storing these somewhere on disk on the host that is unsafe (since adding a new environment variable in the running container does not update this list, it must not be reading it directly in real-time).

In general, I feel like environment variables are not adequate to securely store secret data (even if only temporarily), but I do not have enough knowledge to back up this thought.

What is a secure method for passing secret data to a container?

Comment: Which [operating system](https://docs.docker.com/installation/#installation) is this for?

Comment: is the secret data consistent or different for each container? what exactly is the secret used for?

Comment: @LateralFractal CentOS 7

Comment: @theterribletrivium the secret data is consistent in this exact case (but some may not be). It is used to pass in a password for a first time initialization of a DB user.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Environment variables are the best way to do this, specifically method 2. Docker, by default, does not allow itself to be run by users other than root. Access to the socket is prohibited. I'd say method 2 is reasonably safe, as out of the box if an attacker has root access (and can poke around in your docker containers) you're already in bad shape.

Two Docker security notes in general. Be super cautious with enabling the API, as by default there is no encryption or authentication. They have a way to use certs and TLS that they documented, but proceed with caution.

Also, if possible enable SELinux on your server. Newer versions of it are able to actually see docker containers and automatically build security contexts for each one. This prevents a container compromise from easily moving back into the host. By default docker runs as the root user, and even with the USER directive it still interfaces directly with the kernel unlike a VM. This exposes the host to any local privilege exploit as soon as a docker container is compromised.

Comment: You seem knowledgeable on this topic, so I'll ask: SELinux with containers works best when you can assign an MCS category to the running container, and label the files it needs with that MCS label to prevent other different containers from accessing other containers' files (in the event of a break out). I cannot seem to find a way to set the MCS label on a docker container (it can only be randomly generated), which makes it difficult to deal with when I update the container (i.e. new random label that can't access the files). Do you know if there is a way to handle this?

Comment: Also, how does this change for more persistent info, like say, an ssl private key?

Comment: Can you go into a little more detail in regards to what files you're accessing? I wouldn't typically expect or want one container to talk to another in general, except in cases involving performance or that sort of thing. To the SSL key, it doesn't change it much. Just guard the material the same way you would otherwise.

Comment: The most common scenario I can think of is mounting a DB data volume from the host. If you put out a new db image, I would like to be able to specify the MCS category instead of getting a random one. Interesting, Docker 1.3 was announced a few hours ago and appears to have solved this with the new `--security-opt` command line arg to the run command

Comment: Awesome, I hadn't yet seen that. I know they are working aggressively on those things. This is good news, and I think should help you with the labels.

Comment: @theterribletrivium [using environment variables for secrets](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/13490) is officially considered a hack: `Features / hacks that are (mis)used for secrets`

Answer (score 6):

Docker guys have recently introduced their native solution for this: 
https://blog.docker.com/2017/02/docker-secrets-management/

The usage pattern is:

```
$ echo "This is a secret" | docker secret create my_secret_data -
$ docker service  create --name="redis" --secret="my_secret_data" redis:alpine
```

The  unencrypted secret is then mounted into the container in an in-memory filesystem at `/run/secrets/<secret_name>`.

Though this is only accessible within a `swarm`

You can find full documentation here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/

Comment: This is a great update, but please include the relevant parts of the link in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

## Short answer

`docker build` has [`--secret` option for API version 1.39+](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#options).

## Long answer

### API version 1.39+ means docker 18.09.0+

In release notes, under "New features for Docker Engine EE and CE" section at [18.09.0](https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/#18090) says:

- Updated API version to 1.39 moby/moby#37640

### "Build Enhancements for Docker" page in guides has a bit outdated explanation.

I found `--secret` option at [New Docker Build secret information](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#new-docker-build-secret-information), but the explanation here turned out to be outdated.
It says

> This Dockerfile is only to demonstrate that the secret can be accessed. As you can see the secret printed in the build output. The final image built will not have the secret file

but actually the secret is not printed in the build output. I think it is guarded for security.

### "Dockerfile frontend experimental syntaxes" page in buildkit has up-to-date explanation.

Then I found the following page.

- [buildkit/experimental.md at master ・ moby/buildkit](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/experimental.md)
- [buildkit/experimental.md at 1bf8190 ・ moby/buildkit](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/1bf81905fee37175099507fa82c372f6a490cacd/frontend/dockerfile/docs/experimental.md) as of writing this.

### How to use `docker build --secret`

Here is the steps to follow.

1. Make sure you use the required version of docker.

```
$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.2
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.8
 Git commit:        6a30dfc
 Built:             Thu Aug 29 05:29:11 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.2
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.8
  Git commit:       6a30dfc
  Built:            Thu Aug 29 05:27:45 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.2.6
  GitCommit:        894b81a4b802e4eb2a91d1ce216b8817763c29fb
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc8
  GitCommit:        425e105d5a03fabd737a126ad93d62a9eeede87f
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

2. Set `DOCKER_BUILDKIT` environment variable to `1`

```
$ export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
```

3. Create a secret file.

```
$ echo "It's a secret" > mysecret.txt
```

4. Create a Dockerfile.

```
$ cat <<EOF > Dockerfile
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM alpine
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=mysecret,target=/foobar cat /foobar | tee /output
EOF
```

Make sure you have `# syntax = docker/dockerfile:experimental` at the first line in `Dockerfile`.
Note the above example is just for demo. You should not save the content of secret in actual usage.

5. Run `docker build` with `--secret` option.

```
$ docker build -t secret-example --secret id=mysecret,src=mysecret.txt .
[+] Building 2.3s (8/8) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
 => => transferring dockerfile: 176B
 => [internal] load .dockerignore
 => => transferring context: 2B
 => resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:experimental
 => CACHED docker-image://docker.io/docker/dockerfile:experimental@sha256:888f21826273409b5ef5ff9ceb90c64a8f8ec7760da30d1ffbe6c3e2d323a7bd
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:latest
 => CACHED [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/alpine
 => [2/2] RUN --mount=type=secret,id=mysecret,target=/foobar cat /foobar | tee /output
 => exporting to image
 => => exporting layers
 => => writing image sha256:22c44473107b6d1f92095c6400613a7e82c9835f5baaa85853a114e4bb5d8744
 => => naming to docker.io/library/secret-example
```

Note the content of `mysecret.txt` is NOT printed even in the build output.

Verify the secret is correctly used. Again this is just for demo purpose.

```
$ docker run -t secret-example cat /output
It's a secret
```

I noticed the content of `/foobar` is not saved, but empty file remains in the built image.

```
$ docker run -t secret-example ls -l /foobar
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root             0 Sep 16 19:16 /foobar
```

Comment: I created a real example for gpg clearsign during docker build.
https://github.com/hnakamur/docker-build-secret-example

Answer (score 1):

`docker secret` only works in `swarm` mode. For local mode, to pass some simple secret, such as password, we can read the password into a variable from stdin. The difficulty comes with the `detach` mode, which will hang while reading the pipe within the container. Here is a trick to work around:

```
cid=$(docker run -d -i alpine sh -c 'read A; echo "[$A]"; exec some-server')
docker exec -i $cid sh -c 'cat > /proc/1/fd/0' <<< _a_secret_
```

First, create the docker daemon with `-i` option, the command `read A` will hang waiting for the input from `/proc/1/fd/0`;
Then run the second docker command, reading the secret from stdin and redirect to the last hanging process. The secret will only be read once, and will not be inspected.